# How does I am login in the website still while I cleaned my cookies by my browser

Tags: php, cookies

How does I am login in the website still while I cleaned my cookies by my browser??? 
I have Firefox browser and I did the following operations.

**first** I want to login in a website, at first I send a request to the site and the site checks my input fields and if they are correct, So the website sends to my browser a value and the value will store in a cookie in my browser and then when I send the second request to the website, my browser sends the cookie value also with that and the website gets the cookie value and it compares with its value that was stored on the first request and if it is valid as the result I am login to the site still.

**2-** second, I go to the option item in the Firefox and then I go to the privacy and then I go to the `clear all current history` and then I clean the contents of the `clear all current history` and also the cookies.

**3-** And now I go to the site and I am login still in the site, while I cleaned the cookies from my browser and this is strange???

Comment: because the session is still active

Comment: close the browser and try again

Comment: after closing browser also, session will be active. unless and until we unset the session.